# Does Jnana marga takes much time compared to Karma and Bhakti?

Tags: scripture, moksha, jnana

Traditionally, there are three ways to attain moksha: Jnana, Bhakti, and Karma.

Is it true that it will take **more time** for a person to attain moksha in Jnana marga?

Comment: This is opinion based. It's like who is supreme Shiva or Vishnu?

Answer (score 6):

Karma (i.e. doing actions following Dharma), Bhakti will gradually lead to Jnana and Jnana liberates.

> O King of mountains! Meditation with Karma and Jñâna with Bhakti will
> lead one to Me. Only the work alone will fail to get one to Me. O
> Himavan! **From Dharma arises Bhakti and from Bhakti arises the
> Highest Jñâna.** What are said in the S'ruti and Smriti S'astras the
> Maharsis take that as the Dharma; and what are written in other
> S'astras,
>
> [*The Devi Bhagavata Purana,Book 7, Chapter XXXIX.*](https://www.astrojyoti.com/devigita-8.htm)

So, naturally (and usually) the Jnana stage takes most time and effort to reach.

Comment: Nice answer as usual!

Comment: Thanks! .... @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Rickross can you please have a look at my 2 qns
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/45066/19211
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/45071/19211