# When Mind and Space aren't Brahman why does Chandogya Upanishad ask to meditate on Mind and Space as Brahman?

Tags: advaita, upanishads, brahman

The mind is Brahman—this worship is called adhyātma. Next is that called adhidaivata: Space is Brahman. That is, meditate on space as Brahman. These two ways of meditation are advised: adhyātma and adhidaivata.(Chandogya Upanishad 3.18.1)

Whereas Shankaracharya in his Nirvana Shakta says I am not the mind, the intellect, the ego or the memory and I am the form of consciousness and bliss. Isn't this statement mutually contradictory? Do Upanishads say Mind and Space aren't Brahman??

Comment: Shankaracharya might be referring to dualistic philosophy

Comment: Can you give reference to Shankaracharya's qouted or his writing

Comment: https://isha.sadhguru.org/in/en/blog/article/mystic-chants-nirvana-shatakam
@DarkKnight

Comment: Nirvana Shatkam is a devotional composition. The ultimate aim as per the composition is to realize our true eternal nature as the atman, non different from paramatman, i.e of the form of  Shiva (Shivoham Shivoham), which is Sat-Chitta-Ananda. Inverily though, Brahman is everything, but everything is not Brahman. Like Shankara says in Vishnu Shatpadi - "Samundro hi tarangah kvachana samundro na tarangah" i.e., A tide is always the part of Ocean, but ocean is not a part of the Tide. Similarly, Brahman is everything, yet not everything is Brahman.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru he is speaking about himself and it is more like a dualistic interpretation of self

Comment: Nirvana Shatkam is composed by Shankaracharya to bring senses of gyani inwards in Self, and without bhag or divisions of Maya Bhagwaan who is the cause of divisions in space and time 'Eko ham, bahu syam', 'I am one, let me be many'. "God made sense turn outward, man therefore looks outward, not into himself. Now and again a daring soul, desiring immortality, has looked back and found himself."-Upanishads. Eventually mind and space are also Brahman for a brahmgyani, but not for an animal or extrovert Asura, hence, 'Sarvam Khalvidam Brahman-Everything is Brahman', Chandogya Upanishad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meditation is always graded according to the aspirant and has to undergo various stages. One starts from thinking the body is Brahman, then the mind is Brahman till he realizes that none of these are actually Brahman.

Tai. Upanishad

> Bhrigu is instructed by his father Varuna to realise Brahman.
> Gradually Bhrigu pierced through these various layers of his
> personality. From the five sheaths, he realizes that Bliss is Brahman,
> and the physical, the vital, the mental and the intellectual sheaths
> are not Brahman. Prāṇo brahmeti vyājānat (Tai.Upan. 3.3.1).

Talks with Ramana Maharshi, 146

> When told that you are not the ego, realise the Reality. Why do you
> still identify yourself with the ego? It is like saying, “Don’t think
> of the monkey while taking medicine” - it is impossible. Similarly it
> happens with common folk. When the Reality is mentioned why do you
> continue to meditate Sivoham or Aham Brahmasmi? The significance must
> be traced and understood. It is not enough to repeat the bare words or
> think of them.

The meditation process is a gradual method of freeing consciousness from its entanglement in objects. Various Upanishads talks about various kinds of meditations: meditation on Vaishvanara, Hiranyagarbha, Ishvara, Omkara etc. but the ultimate purpose is Atma sakshatkara, or the realisation of Brahman.

Answer (score 0):

> mano buddhi ahankara chittani naaham
> na cha shrotravjihve na cha ghraana netre
> na cha vyoma bhumir na tejo na vaayuhu
> chidananda rupah shivo'ham shivo'ham
>
> > I am not the mind, the intellect, the ego or the memory,
> > I am not the ears, the skin, the nose or the eyes,
> > I am not space, not earth, not fire, water or wind,
> > I am the form of consciousness and bliss,
> > **I am the eternal Shiva**...

This is a devotional poem.

The main thing in the poem is to realize the self or to realize we to also divine.

We are the spark of the divine Shiva. That's what it means.